# OS X NSDatePicker - how to set calendar to Today

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, datepicker

I have a "Today" button to reset a datePicker to today's date. This works for the current month, but not for other months.

The method is:

```
- (IBAction)setToday:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [datePicker setDateValue:[NSDate date]];
    [datePicker setNeedsDisplay: YES];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by: "This works for the current month, but not for other months."?

Comment: Today is "Dec. 6". If I select "Dec. 24", the focus moves to Dec. 24. If I click the "Today" button, the focus returns to Dec. 6. However, if I move to "Jan 1" and click the Today button, nothing happens.

Comment: I tried your code -- worked fine for me. Try cleaning your project and try again. When you say nothing happens, do you still get the log?

Comment: Thanks very much for looking. I think I have a problem with the bindings, and that's causing the button method to be wonky.

Comment: oh, and yes, the log shows that the method is firing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your date picker is a property, in which case you should use the self keyword.

```
self.datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
```

Comment: Thanks very much Adam. That was it!